ArgoCD Default and overwrite source path
I am trying ArgoCD product as a solution for Kubernetes Infra installation (RBACs, Namespaces and third party charts)
I want to use the main branch on my repo and it will contains a path that look like that:
<Env>
│
├── defaults
│   ├── YAMLS
│   │   ├── rbac.yaml
│   │   └── namespaces.yaml
│   │
│   └── Charts
│       ├── <xxxx>
│       └── <xxxx>
│
├── Cluster-Name-1
│   ├── YAMLS
│   │   ├── rbac.yaml
│   │   └── namespaces.yaml
│   │
│   └── Charts
│       ├── <xxxx>
│       └── <xxxx>
│
└── Cluster-Name-2
    ├── YAMLS
    │   ├── rbac.yaml
    │   └── namespaces.yaml
    │
    └── Charts
        ├── <xxxx>
        └── <xxxx>


I want a cluster to apply the default path of the env if a folder named the name of the cluster is not exist, but if a dir named by the cluster name is exist in the path of the env, it will use it as a source.
for example, if I have cluster-name-3 it will use the default path, but cluster-name-1 and 2 will use their own path and overwrite the default path.
Thanks for your assistance.

What have you tried? It should be simple enough to create a script to check if a path exists, and if it doesn't use the default one.

I am trying to avoid bash scripts, I would like to check if we have any mechanized for it on ArgoCD because it looks like pretty standard case if you want to have default path.
I tried couple of things for example sync-wave or stuff like that but it merge the sources instead of chose priority for the cluster path if exist
